# Getting undefined Error in a Loop even after accessing data

Tags: javascript

I am working on the following code. Why am I getting this error:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",

while getting the result back from the loop?

[image]

```js
var ifclus = [["-9.00", "-6.50"], ["-6.00", "+6.00"]];
for (var i = 0; i <= ifclus.length; i++) {
  var start = parseFloat(ifclus[i][0]).toFixed(2);
  var end = parseFloat(ifclus[i][1]).toFixed(2);
 console.log(start)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `i <= ifclus.length` looks like it should be `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `ifclus.length` is 2

and according to your condition `i <= ifclus.length` loop will run for `0, 1, 2`

and ifclus[2] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're just looping over more than you should. 
Should be

`i < ifclus.length`

instead of

`i <= ifclus.length`

in the loop.

An honest mistake.